# How to manage concurrency with multiple consumers on single queue with RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, .net-core

I would like to create queue that will receive multiple messages with some identifier. I would like to process this queue asynchronously but with one condition, if consumer is working on message with identifier x, no other messages with same identifier can be published to other consumers. Once consumer is done with that message it reports back and messages with that identifier can be published again.

Basically queue will branch out to multiple channels where each channel will represent an identifier and messages in those channels will be sorted by time they arrived, and each messages in channel will be handled synchronously but channels in queue asynchronously.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

> Is that even possible?

not directly in RabbitMQ, no.

I have similar requirements in one of my systems, and handled it all in my code for the message producers.